# Systemd Fedora 25 startup script permission denied

Tags: systemd, startup

I have been following numerous tutorials on how to write a startup script for systemd (Fedora 25 on Vbox). However, I'm not able to make it work.

Here is the bash script `/home/dario/Desktop/unix/SYSTEMD/print_date.sh` that I want to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
date > startup_date
```

I changed permissions on the file, `chmod 755 print_date.sh`

I created the service file `/etc/systemd/system/print_date.service` (this is just the last versions, I tried out many other iterations):

```
[Unit]
Description=Example startup script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/dario/Desktop/unix/SYSTEMD/print_date.sh
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable print_date
```

and to test it out witout rebooting

```
systemctl start print_date
```

which gives me the error

```
[root@dario SYSTEMD]# systemctl start print_date
Job for print_date.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status print_date.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

If I try to debug it with journal -xn the result is:

```
[root@dario SYSTEMD]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Wed 2016-12-28 13:03:41 PST, end at Sat 2017-03-18 12:25:39 PDT. --
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario systemd[4143]: print_date.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/dario/Desktop/unix/SYSTEMD/print_date.sh: Permissi
-- Subject: Process /home/dario/Desktop/unix/SYSTEMD/print_date.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /home/dario/Desktop/unix/SYSTEMD/print_date.sh could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario systemd[1]: print_date.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario systemd[1]: Failed to start Example startup script.
-- Subject: Unit print_date.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit print_date.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario systemd[1]: print_date.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=print_date
Mar 18 12:25:35 dario systemd[1]: print_date.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 12:25:38 dario dbus-daemon[682]: [system] Activating service name='org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd' requested by ':1.36' (uid=0 pid=6
Mar 18 12:25:38 dario dbus-daemon[682]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd'
```

Comment: There might be multiple problems, but try `Type=oneshot` instead of forking.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a suitable answer for me.
However, please elaborate if you have a solution that is not as drastic as mine.

In my case, the problem relies in SELinux default mode, which is set as *enforcing*. By setting SELinux to *permissive* I can allow my script to be run at startup (and whenever I test it out with systemctl start ..).

I don't really understand the details of SELinux and it feels like I'm messing with something bigger then me. I invite other people to expand on this solution in a more professional way.

In `/etc/selinux/config`

set the line

```
SELINUX = enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX = permissive
```

It would allow the execution of the startup file.
Regards.